# How to fix CORS issues with API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

All of a sudden this morning when I'm trying to invoke my lambda via api gateway it stopped working which is really irritating.

I've done all the following normal things:

- my integration type is "Lambda Function" and i have `Use Lambda Proxy
- integration` ticked I've enabled CORS on my API.
- I've re-deployed my API many times I'm invoking the correct URL

my lambda contains this:

```
    callback(null, {
        body: JSON.stringify('Successfully set in firebase!'),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        statusCode: 200,
    })
```

I'm getting this error too in lambda:

The API with ID XXXXX doesn’t include a resource with path / having an integration arn:XXXX on the POST method. not sure if this is relevant?

no idea why it stopped working. any ideas?

Comment: Why do you think its CORS issue? Seems to me that the Lambda is failing because your API GAteway doesn't have a resource for the path "/"

Comment: getting a CORS failure in the console. anyway I think I solved that but now im getting null in the body of my api response?

Comment: @mokugo-devops what does that error even mean and how can I fix it ?

Comment: In API Gateway set a resource on the root of the API Gateway. Although I presume that if you aren't trying to access the root that you actually have an error in the application thats calling it

Comment: I do. I have a GET resource on the root. so not sure why it's complaining. plus that resource works. this is turning into a hellish afternoon. no idea why it's starting to flake out and I keep getting CORS issues

Comment: It might be that its hitting a http method other than get?

Comment: I've added a POST in there and it fixed that. no idea why it needs that but anyway. still getting stupid cors issues. interestingly when I comment out most of my lambda function I don't get the CORS issues. but when I test lambda in console, it's fine?